Initial values for GEV parameters in maximum likelihood method
When estimating the parameters for GEV distribution by the Maximum Likelihood Method, having the log-likelihood function, one may try to find the maximum using a quasi-Newton method like Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno, or if you add the derivatives of the log-likelihood function, Newton like methods can be used. In any situation, the convergence of the algorithm and the final solution, are highly dependent of the initial approximations chosen for the values of the parameters. I found in literature that the location cam be initial approximated by the mean of the sample, the scale by the standard deviation or with the IQR of the sample and the shape with the value obtained by the method of moments.
I was wandering if there are some other recommendations how to choose the initial approximations for the location, scale and shape?

Try to find a closed-form estimator using a different estimation method
When looking for initial values for iterative optimisation algorithms, it is often useful to use some closed form estimator that uses a different estimation method or which solves things for a special case for the distribution in question.  One reasonable method is to look at the form of the moments of the distribution and see if you can form closed form estimators using the method-of-moments or the method-of-quantiles, either for the general form of the distribution or for a special case.

In the case of the GEV distribution there are various approaches and options that you might use, but I will show you one example.  Suppose we have $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{IID GEV}(\mu, \sigma, \xi)$.  For the special case where $\xi = 0$ (and letting $\gamma$ denote the Euler–Mascheroni constant) we have the moments:
$$\mathbb{E}(X_i) = \mu + \gamma \cdot \sigma 
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\mathbb{S}(X_i) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{6}} \cdot \sigma,$$
which gives the parameter expressions:
$$\mu = \mathbb{E}(X_i) - \sqrt{\frac{6 \gamma^2}{\pi}} \cdot \mathbb{S}(X_i) 
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi}} \cdot \mathbb{S}(X_i).$$
Using a method-of-moments estimator with sample mean $\bar{x}_n$ and sample standard deviation $s_n$ gives:
$$\hat{\mu} = \bar{x}_n - \sqrt{\frac{6 \gamma^2}{\pi}} \cdot s_n 
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi}} \cdot s_n.$$
Moreover, the entropy for the distribution is:
$$H(X_i) = \log(\sigma) + \gamma \xi + \gamma + 1,$$
which gives the parameter expression:
$$\xi = \frac{H(X_i) - \log(\sigma) - \gamma - 1}{\gamma}.$$
Taking $h_n$ as the sample entropy gives:
$$\hat{\xi} = \frac{h_n - \tfrac{1}{2} \log(6/\pi) - \log(s_n) - \gamma - 1}{\gamma}.$$
This gives you closed-form expressions for each of the parameter estimators in terms of the sample mean $\bar{x}_n$, the sample variance $s_n$ and the sample entropy $h_n$.  You could try these estimators as your initial values for the optimisation algorithm and see if you get good convergence in your algorithm.  However, because the support of the distribution is restricted, you should ensure that these estimates give you a valid support that is consistent with your data (and vary the initial estimate if the support is invalid).
